# High Speed Camera?

Tags: camera, htc-one

Since my phone (HTC One M7) can record in 720p at 60 fps, I'm curious if it's possible to record smaller video, like 320x240, at much higher speeds, like 180 fps.

Is the 60 fps a hard coded limit?

Comment: I believe the phones codec limits it to a speed that can be played on the phone. Even if you could film at 180 fps, where would you play it?

Comment: @BobbyAlexander On my desktop, I suspect?

Comment: This article might help: http://www.theguardian.com/technology/askjack/2013/jan/10/camera-shooting-slow-motion-videos

Answer (score 0):

A lot of devices are limited by the camera sensor used, even if the device is powerful enough, you may not be able to record at 180fps because the camera module cannot process data fast enough. The HTC One(M7) camera is limited to 96fps at best. The best on a mobile camera is at 120fps right now.

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge, I have not seen such option in HTC One that you can use.
Now, if you are asking if TECHNICALLY that would be possible, I really doubt it to achieve 180 fps.

Though some serious(?) hacks can increase the fps, but I believe there is a physical ccd sensor limitation in place. Otherwise, DSLR camera owners would have been able to turn their Full HD cameras into low-res high speed camcorders.